# Throwing std::exception in CLI throws Access Violation

Tags: c++, exception, access-violation

I am forced to use CLI because of some C# dependencies in my C++ code.
Before this dependency came in, I wrote an exception, which inherits from std::exception. Whenever I throw this exception now, my program crashes with an access violation exception comming from ntd.dll.

So I put the header file, which contains the exception in a new CLI project and tried to compile it. This gave me the error, that "exception" is not a member of std. After including `<exception>`, this error was gone (of course), but I wonder, why this wasn't necessary before..
Anyways, here's my code in the basic example:

The exception header:

```
#pragma once

#include <exception>

//Device is offline
struct E_DvcOffline : public std::exception
{
    const char * what() const throw ()
    {
        return "The Device is offline";
    }
};
```

The main function:

```
#include <MyExceptions.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace System;




int main(array<String^>^ args) {

    try {

        throw E_DvcOffline();
    }
    catch (E_DvcOffline) {

        std::cout << "Caught it" << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();
    }


}
```

And the exception I receive, when the code throws my custom exception:

[Not able to embed pictures yet...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qEPD.png)

Thanks in advance,
Calvin

**EDIT**

`throw new E_DvcOffline();` changed to `throw E_DvcOffline();`

Comment: Change `throw new E_DvcOffline();` to `throw E_DvcOffline();`

Comment: *Why wasn't it necessary before?* Because some other header that you were including was also including <exception>. System headers are allowed to include each other, so that was probably what was happening in your case.

Comment: Damn, I forgot to remove "new" after just testing it like this. I'm not using "new" in production and receive the same error. @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: @john This is true. But intellisense told me, that exception is no element of std in the actual header file containing the exception. Which, as you see, doesn't include anything besides the newly included <exception>.

Comment: @Calvin Also you should catch by reference, not by value `catch (const & E_DvcOffline) {`

Comment: @Calvin In your original project you probably included <MyExceptions.hpp> after another header that did include <exception>. Which is the reason that it's advised to include your headers first before any system headers, so dependencies like this are more likely to be picked up.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Actually `catch (const & E_DvcOffline) {` yields an error by intellisense. "Missing explicit type (assuming int)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem.

```
#pragma once
**#pragma managed(push, off)**

#include <exception>

//Device is offline
struct E_DvcOffline : public std::exception
{
    const char * what() const throw ()
    {
        return "The Device is offline";
    }
};
**#pragma managed(pop)**
```

Changes are bolt. 
I didn't search for it, but I think, that this tells the compiler to treat this code as unmanaged and therefore calls the native exception handler.

**Warning**: Visual Studio will eventually yield the same error as before, when you go through the code step by step in debug mode. Otherwise everything works fine.